# Download directory of images from amazon s3 to android adapter

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-adapter

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with a number of directories. I am interested in one particular directory that contains a number of photos. I want to download all the photos in that directory for display in an android adapter. How might I do that? The adapter displays images of course.

I am asking because it is not clear that TransferUtility provides such mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

TransferUtility doesn't support downloading an S3 directory (or prefix). You can list objects in S3 directory and add them to TransferUtility. Attach a listener to each download. Once a download is completed, display it with the adapter.

BTW, [MobileHub](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/) can generate a sample for you to show how to do download files in an S3 directory with TransferUtility.